# MySQL erro ao somar valores

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Bom dia,

Pessoal estou enfrentando o seguinte problema, tenho uma tabela "produtos", onde tem dois 2 produtos, segue o exemplo:

id = 30105
total = 20.00
comissao = 12
quantidade = 3

id = 30072
total = 200.00
comissao = 13
quantidade = 1

```
SELECT (SUM(total - (total / 100 * comissao)) * quantidade) AS totalliberar FROM produtos WHERE (id = '30105')
```

totalliberar = **52,80**

```
SELECT (SUM(total - (total / 100 * comissao)) * quantidade) AS totalliberar FROM produtos WHERE (id = '30072')
```

totalliberar = **174,00**

SOMANDO OS DOIS VALORES
**52,80 + 174,00 = 226,80**

Porém quando coloco a query para somar os dois, o produto "30105" o MySQL faz a quantidade = 1 e não quantidade = 3 (que seria o correto) e o valor fica 17,60, somando 174,00 + 17,60 = 191,60 e não retornando 226,80.

```
SELECT (SUM(total - (total / 100 * comissao)) * quantidade) AS totalliberar FROM produtos WHERE (id = '30105' OR id = '30072')
```

totalliberar = **191,60**

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Você está fazendo `SUM(...) * quantidade`. Se a soma é uma função agregadora, qual seria o valor de `quantidade` que deveria ser considerado? Provavelmente esse `quantidade` deveria estar dentro do `SUM`.

Comment: Resolvido! burrice mesmo! SELECT (SUM((total - (total / 100 * comissao)) * quantidade)) AS totalliberar FROM produtos WHERE (id = '30105' OR id = '30072')

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido! Obrigado Woss!

```
SELECT (SUM((total - (total / 100 * comissao)) * quantidade)) AS totalliberar FROM compras_produtos WHERE (id = '30105' OR id = '30072')
```